# Build fixed interval dataset from random interval dataset using stale data

Tags: performance, matlab

**Update:** I've provided a brief analysis of the three answers at the bottom of the question text and explained my choices.

**My Question:** What is the most efficient method of building a fixed interval dataset from a random interval dataset using stale data?

**Some background:** The above is a common problem in statistics. Frequently, one has a sequence of observations occurring at random times. Call it `Input`. But one wants a sequence of observations occurring say, every 5 minutes. Call it `Output`. One of the most common methods to build this dataset is using stale data, i.e. set each observation in `Output` equal to the most recently occurring observation in `Input`.

So, here is some code to build example datasets:

```
TInput = 100;
TOutput = 50;

InputTimeStamp = 730486 + cumsum(0.001 * rand(TInput, 1));
Input = [InputTimeStamp, randn(TInput, 1)];

OutputTimeStamp = 730486.002 + (0:0.001:TOutput * 0.001 - 0.001)';
Output = [OutputTimeStamp, NaN(TOutput, 1)];
```

Both datasets start at close to midnight at the turn of the millennium. However, the timestamps in `Input` occur at random intervals while the timestamps in `Output` occur at fixed intervals. For simplicity, I have ensured that the first observation in `Input` always occurs before the first observation in `Output`. Feel free to make this assumption in any answers.

Currently, I solve the problem like this:

```
sMax = size(Output, 1);
tMax = size(Input, 1);
s = 1;
t = 2;
%#Loop over input data
while t <= tMax
    if Input(t, 1) > Output(s, 1)
        %#If current obs in Input occurs after current obs in output then set current obs in output equal to previous obs in input
        Output(s, 2:end) = Input(t-1, 2:end);
        s = s + 1;
        %#Check if we've filled out all observations in output
        if s > sMax
            break
        end
        %#This step is necessary in case we need to use the same input observation twice in a row
        t = t - 1;
    end
    t = t + 1;
    if t > tMax
        %#If all remaining observations in output occur after last observation in input, then use last obs in input for all remaining obs in output 
        Output(s:end, 2:end) = Input(end, 2:end);
        break
    end
end
```

Surely there is a more efficient, or at least, more elegant way to solve this problem? As I mentioned, this is a common problem in statistics. Perhaps Matlab has some in-built function I'm not aware of? Any help would be much appreciated as I use this routine a LOT for some large datasets.

**THE ANSWERS:** Hi all, I've analyzed the three answers, and as they stand, Angainor's is the best.

ChthonicDaemon's answer, while clearly the easiest to implement, is really slow. This is true even when the conversion to a `timeseries` object is done outside of the speed test. I'm guessing the `resample` function has a lot of overhead at the moment. I am running 2011b, so it is possible Mathworks have improved it in the intervening time. Also, this method needs an additional line for the case where `Output` ends more than one observation after `Input`.

Rody's answer runs only slightly slower than Angainor's (unsurprising given they both employ the `histc` approach), however, it seems to have some problems. First, the method of assigning the last observation in `Output` is not robust to the last observation in `Input` occurring after the last observation in `Output`. This is an easy fix. But there is a second problem which I think stems from having `InputTimeStamp` as the first input to `histc` instead of the `OutputTimeStamp` adopted by Angainor. The problem emerges if you change `OutputTimeStamp = 730486.002 + (0:0.001:TOutput * 0.001 - 0.001)';` to `OutputTimeStamp = 730486.002 + (0:0.0001:TOutput * 0.0001 - 0.0001)';` when setting up the example inputs.

Angainor's appears robust to everything I threw at it, plus it was the fastest.

I did a lot of speed tests for different input specifications - the following numbers are fairly representative:

My naive loop: `Elapsed time is 8.579535 seconds.`

**Angainor**: `Elapsed time is 0.661756 seconds.`

Rody: `Elapsed time is 0.913304 seconds.`

ChthonicDaemon: `Elapsed time is 22.916844 seconds.`

I'm +1-ing Angainor's solution and marking the question solved.

Comment: Just to be clear: is it important that the times are not in order? In most cases observations are made in strictly ascending time.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon You can assume times are in ascending order. I appear to have both the `timeseries` class and `resample` function in 2011b, so I should be able to test your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on the problem. `histc` is the way to go:

```
% find Output timestamps in Input bins
N   = histc(Output(:,1), Input(:,1));

% find counts in the non-empty bins
counts = N(find(N));

% find Input signal value associated with every bin
val = Input(find(N),2);

% now, replicate every entry entry in val
% as many times as specified in counts
index = zeros(1,sum(counts));
index(cumsum([1 counts(1:end-1)'])) = 1;
index = cumsum(index);
val_rep = val(index)

% finish the signal with last entry from Input, as needed
val_rep(end+1:size(Output,1)) = Input(end,2);

% done
Output(:,2) = val_rep;
```

I checked against your procedure for a few different input models (I changed the number of Output timestamps) and the results are the same. However, I am still not sure I understood your problem, so if something is wrong here let me know.

Comment: I've explained my choices and added a brief analysis of all 3 answers to the bottom of the question text. Thanks again for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

This "stale data" approach is known as a [zero order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) in signal and timeseries fields. Searching for this quickly brings up many solutions. If you have Matlab 2012b, this is all built in to the [`timeseries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseriesclass.html) class by using the `resample` function, so you would simply do

```
TInput = 100;
TOutput = 50;

InputTimeStamp = 730486 + cumsum(0.001 * rand(TInput, 1));
InputData = randn(TInput, 1);
InputTimeSeries = timeseries(InputData, InputTimeStamp);

OutputTimeStamp = 730486.002 + (0:0.001:TOutput * 0.001 - 0.001);
OutputTimeSeries = resample(InputTimeSeries, OutputTimeStamp, 'zoh'); % zoh stands for zero order hold
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think the `sort` is necessary as the output of `rand` is strictly positive, so a cumulative sum over it should be monotonically increasing yes?

Comment: I've explained my choices and added a brief analysis of all 3 answers to the bottom of the question text. Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: I missed the cumsum part, thanks. I'm a bit surprised that the built-in resample is so slow, but I suppose it's like a lot of things in Matlab, the general approach does a lot of checking to ensure robustness, etc.